# Can I access(and change) a property of smtp-connector programmatically?

Tags: java, mule, mule-el

I am running mule 3.3.1 CE.

I have an use case for which I need to be able to dynamically set the mime type on a smtp endpoint. But it appears I am unable to do so as it is currently bugged:
https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6005

Also, if I use MEL to try and set the mime type like this:

```
mimeType="#[message.payload['email-mime']]"
```

All I get is bunch of stacktraces, and the application won't even deploy.

> ERROR 2014-02-17 16:28:58,153 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1]
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
>   org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested
>   PropertyAccessException details (1) are: PropertyAccessException 1:
>   org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property
>   'mimeType' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find a sub type.
>           at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1167)
>           at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:924)

Is there a way to access the connector itself during runtime, and perhaps be able to change it so I would be able to change the mime type as needed? Or an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a separate `smtp:connector` like in the Jira description and try to set the content type in a Groovy script somewhere inside the flow like this:

```
muleContext.getRegistry().lookupObject('smtpConnector').setContentType('text/html')
```

Comment: Or use MEL: `#[app.registry.smtpConnector.contentType='text/html']`

Comment: @DavidDossot I was able to solve this using the MEL expression you provided. Along the lines of #[app.registry.smtpConnector.contentType='#[header:mimetype]']. I'll edit in the final solution tomorrow.